# The datalist does not show the values

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am developing an application in google app script, and I have a problem that is the following:
I have a list of data in a google spreadsheet, I am trying to display this list in the html, however nothing is displayed, the code is as follows.

File attached

Code scipt

```
var sheet   =  SpreadsheetApp.openById("xxxxxxxxxxxx").getSheetByName("Listas");
var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();  
var lasColum = sheet.getLastColumn();
var myRange = sheet.getRange("A2:A"+lastRow);
var data    = myRange.getValues();

function getOptionsCargos(){
  var data = sheet.getRange(1,2).getDataRegion().getValues();
 
  return data.sort().map(d => "<option>" +d+ "</option>").join();
 
}
```

Html

```
<div class="mb-2">
<label for="apellidos" class="form-label">Apellidos</label>
   <input type="text" class="form-control" name="apellidos" id="apellidos" pattern="[^0-9]*" title="El nombre no puede contener números" list="lista" required>
      <datalist id="lista">
           <?!=getOptionsCargos()?>'

      </datalist>
 </div>
```

I hope someone can help me

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Display Data in html:

gs:

```
function lfunko() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1zKx8B4jSRTUue9npBoB6IolW6-u-LcllZJNLh8tQkzY");
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName("Listas");
  var myRange = sh.getRange("A2:A" + sh.getLastRow());
  var data = myRange.getValues().flat().join("<br>");
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(data),"List Data in Dialog");
}
```

or

gs:

```
    function lfunko() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  var myRange = sh.getRange("A2:A" + sh.getLastRow());
  var data = myRange.getValues();
  return data;
}

function runthis(){
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('ah1').evaluate(),'My List');
}
```

html:(file:ah2.html)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <base target="_top">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="tabledata">
       <? var vs = lfunko(); ?>
       <table>
         <? vs.forEach((r,i)=>{ ?>
           <tr>
           <? r.forEach((c,j)=>{ ?>
             <? if(i == 0) { ?>
            <th style="padding:2px 5px;font-weight:bold;border:1px solid black;"><?= c ?> </th>           
           <? } else { ?>
             <td style="padding:2px 5px;border:1px solid black;"><?= vs[i][j] ?> </td>
           <? } ?>
         <?  }); ?>
           </tr>
         <? }); ?>
       </table>
     </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much friend, I've tried it and it doesn't work. Can you check my spreadsheet please. Specifically the main.html file

Comment: I just tested both of them and they both work for me.  You may need to edit them to work for you.  Like sheet names id's etc.  Put your thinking cap on.

Comment: How are you launching your dialog?

Comment: You need to put everything necessary for the question in the question.